# SKErrorUnknown while testing in-app purchase

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am working to implement in-app purchase for a project and everything went well except the actual test purchase:
- I created the app in iTunes (unique ID, submited a binary, then rejected it because this is not the final one)
- created the in-app purchase items
- implemented the code
- created the test account

What is working:
- I got a valid product from store
- I got the "Confirm your subscription..." popup
- I got the "Share your information ..." popup
- and then i got this error: Code=0 “Cannot connect to iTunes Store” (SKErrorUnknown)

Does anyone have any idea on this one ? (I've been googling for two days ... and nothing seems to work).

Thanks.

Comment: is there any chance that you are running on a jailbroken device?

Comment: No, the device is not jailbroken (it's my device, I bought it for new)

Comment: what does the error message say? is it Code=0 “Cannot connect to iTunes Store” (SKErrorUnknown) ?

Comment: The Code is 0, I'll check what contains the domain property and I'll get back (I'm not near the device at the moment)

Comment: I've just checked and the domain is SKErrorDomain

Comment: let's see what does [yourError localizedDescription] say

Comment: I've just checked and the domain is SKErrorDomain (the user info is"Cannot connect to iTunes store")

Comment: okay, try to look around here with the error description, there is plenty of possible solutions (e.g. create new test user, remove app from the phone, restart, check with a network tool whether you access sandbox or regular store, etc.)

Comment: well ... nothing seems to work (tried new user, clean build, restart, new in-app products, debug and release builds, moving the store calls from application delegate to main view loop) What would be the solution if the app is connecting to the real store instead of sandbox ? (in the popups "confirm your subscription" it mentions that is the sandbox environment)

Comment: well, if you are sure the productId are valid, you might try log-in (from Settings.app) with your regular appstore account and then sign out&try the test user. As the last resort i would try erase settings/restore the device (if is this a test device and you won't mind)

Comment: still get the error after login-logout with my personal account. Unfortunately it's not a test device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've found my problem:my app was enabled only for Romania, my test user was localized for Romania - and with this setup does not work.

I've enabled the app for USA and created a test user localized in USA and it seems to work (no code change at all). And I think that proves that the code is ok, just the apple sandbox has some problems with non USA test users.

Comment: I am getting `SKErrorUnknown` on user cancel, (instead of getting `SKErrorPaymentCancelled`), and all my test users are based on the japanese store (non-US). Did you experience the same when cancelling a purchase?

Comment: I never successfully tested a non-US test user ... so, I'm olny using US test users after experiencing those errors