# In-App Purchase Error 0

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I got a problem that I don't know how to fix it. Please help!

When my app tries to purchase in sandbox, it always receives the error SKErrorUnknown. I have tried the ways mentioned in these threads but not work for me:
[Apple In-App Purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872788/in-app-purchase) 
[SKErrorUnknown while testing in-app purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495739/skerrorunknown-while-testing-in-app-purchase) 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670739/in-app-purchase-error-solving

I searched on google but still no help.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

1. The app can get the product from AppStore successfully.
2. The confirm dialog appears.
3. After I click the "Buy" button, the app receives the error.
4. The description of the error is "Cannot connect to iTunes Store."
5. I'm using XCode4.2

Comment: Have You created a test user?

Comment: I've tried 3 different test accounts but none of them works.

Comment: you created your account in itunes connect? as a Test User?

Comment: I didn't create them myself. They were created by someone else in our company. We share these accounts in our team. Everything seems fine several days before.

Comment: ok
now create new account and log out from settings -> store -> log out
before runnin your app and dont sign in with any other account Before.

Comment: @orazran I've tested another account and it's OK now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Youre Welcome if you have any other issues feel free

Comment: You should provide the above discussion as an answer, and accept it.

Comment: @TimBüthe Thanks for your advice. I just post the answer and I will accept it as soon as I can do that.

Comment: @MaTingchen don't edit the title of your question to add [SOLVED]. The accepted answer shows us this :)

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Cannot connect to iTunes Store" in-app purchase problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402801/cannot-connect-to-itunes-store-in-app-purchase-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I searched and tried for a whole day, finally @orazran gave me the answer:

JUST CREATE A NEW TEST ACCOUNT.

If anyone meets the problem again, please try this simple step first.

Answer (score 1):

Did you create a new Test User? iTunes Connect -> Manage Users -> Test User? Right? What to do further?

Answer (score 0):

I searched this question for a long time,finally,I watched the Documentation and API Reference:

Constants
SKErrorUnknown
Indicates that an unknown or unexpected error occurred.

Available in iOS 3.0 and later.
SKErrorClientInvalid
Indicates that the client is not allowed to perform the attempted action.

Available in iOS 3.0 and later.
SKErrorPaymentCancelled
Indicates that the user cancelled a payment request.

Available in iOS 3.0 and later.
SKErrorPaymentInvalid
Indicates that one of the payment parameters was not recognized by the Apple App Store.

Available in iOS 3.0 and later.
SKErrorPaymentNotAllowed
Indicates that the user is not allowed to authorize payments.

Available in iOS 3.0 and later.
SKErrorStoreProductNotAvailable
Indicates that the requested product is not available in the store.

Available in iOS 6.0 and later.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my new created sandox account. I just disconnected my real itunes account from my iphone in

> Setting /  / iTunes Store and App Store / Id Apple (first line)

and connected my sandbox account in

> Setting /  / iTunes Store and App Store / Sandbox (at bottom)